# Is there a more Pythonic approach to this?

Tags: python

This is my first python script, be ye warned.

I pieced this together from Dive Into Python, and it works great.  However since it is my first Python script I would appreciate any tips on how it can be made better or approaches that may better embrace the Python way of programming.

```
import os
import shutil

def getSourceDirectory():
    """Get the starting source path of folders/files to backup"""
    return "/Users/robert/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/"

def getDestinationDirectory():
    """Get the starting destination path for backup"""
    return "/Users/robert/Desktop/Backup/"

def walkDirectory(source, destination):
    """Walk the path and iterate directories and files"""

    sourceList = [os.path.normcase(f)
        for f in os.listdir(source)]

    destinationList = [os.path.normcase(f)
        for f in os.listdir(destination)]

    for f in sourceList:
        sourceItem = os.path.join(source, f)
        destinationItem = os.path.join(destination, f)  

        if os.path.isfile(sourceItem):
            """ignore system files"""
            if f.startswith("."):
                continue

            if not f in destinationList:
                "Copying file: " + f
                shutil.copyfile(sourceItem, destinationItem)

        elif os.path.isdir(sourceItem):
            if not f in destinationList:
                print "Creating dir: " + f
                os.makedirs(destinationItem)

            walkDirectory(sourceItem, destinationItem)

"""Make sure starting destination path exists"""
source = getSourceDirectory()
destination = getDestinationDirectory()

if not os.path.exists(destination):
    os.makedirs(destination)

walkDirectory(source, destination)
```

Comment: I must be losing it, I don't see the Community Wiki field in the form, this should be a Community Wiki

Comment: There is no more CW. It's been removed.

Comment: @JoshD: I apparently didn't get the memo.  I also don't put my headers on my TPS reports, but I am not convinced those two are related.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67039/what-can-we-do-to-make-community-wiki-better

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As others mentioned, you probably want to use `walk` from the built-in `os` module.  Also, consider using [PEP 8 compatible style](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) (no camel-case but `this_stye_of_function_naming()`).  Wrapping directly executable code (i.e. no library/module) into a `if __name__ == '__main__': ...` block is also a good practice.

Comment: I started to look at the style guide on python.org, but I used Dive Into Python as my starting point for functionality.  Is Dive Into Python totally jacked in terms of syntax?

Comment: Also if I can, why does the os package not use "_"?  Ex. "isfile", "makedirs", etc.

Comment: Never mind, "The naming conventions of Python's library are a bit of a mess, so we'll never get this completely consistent", oh man...

Answer (score 4):

The code

- has no docstring describing what it does
- re-invents the "battery" of [shutil.copytree](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html#shutil.copytree)
- has a function called `walkDirectory` which doesn't do what its name implies
- contains `get*` functions that provide no utility

  - those get functions embed high-level arguments deeper than they ought
- is obligatorily chatty (`print` whether you want it or not)

Comment: You mixed in general complaints about the coding style, but did so in a non-verbose, non-disturbing way. This is exactly what I expect from quality answers on SO.  (+1)

Comment: Does shutil.copytree really do the same thing? "The destination directory, named by dst, must not already exist".  The script I wrote doesn't dumb copy the entire source every time, it checks for new files that haven't already been copied.  Am I missing something?

Comment: The whole thing with "walk" is totally valid.  I was going to pass a function to the function to do the actual logic, good catch.

Comment: No, it isn't an exact replacement for shutil.copytree in all aspects, true. However, when creating a feature with similar operation to an existing standard facility, it is good to follow the general approach of the other for if you know `copytree(...)` then your new `update_tree(...)` will be easier to remember and use.

Answer (score 3):

Use [os.path.walk](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.walk).  It does most all the bookkeeping for you; you then just feed a visitor function to it to do what you need.

Or, oh damn, looks like os.path.walk has been deprecated.  Use [os.walk](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.walk) then, and you get

```
for r, d, f in os.walk('/root/path')
    for file in f:
       # do something good.
```

Comment: Isn't os.path.walk deprecated in favor of os.walk?  >>>Note This function is deprecated and has been removed in 3.0 in favor of os.walk().  (from the bottom of http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html)

Comment: yeah, caught that myself.  I can't keep up with the deprecations.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using [os.walk](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.walk). It does what it looks like you're doing. It offers a nice interface that's easy to utilize to do whatever you need.

Answer (score 1):

The main thing to make things more Pythonic is to adopt Python's PEP8, the style guide. It uses underscore for functions.<sup>1</sup>

If you're returning a fixed string, e.g. your get* functions, a variable is probably a 
better approach. By this, I mean replace your `getSourceDirectory` with something like this:

```
source_directory = "/Users/robert/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/"
```

Adding the following conditional will mean that code that is specific for running the module as a program does not get called when the module is imported.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    source = getSourceDirectory()
    destination = getDestinationDirectory()

    if not os.path.exists(destination):
        os.makedirs(destination)

    walkDirectory(source, destination)
```

I would use a `try` & `except` block, rather than a conditional to test if `walkDirectory` can operate successfully. Weird things can happen with multiple processes & filesystems:

```
try:
    walkDirectory(source, destination)
except IOError:
    os.makedirs(destination)
    walkDirectory(source, destination)
```

<sup>1</sup> I've left out discussion about whether to use the standard library. At this stage of your Python journey, I think you're just after a feel how the language should be used in general terms. I don't think knowing the details of `os.walk` is really that important right now.